# How do I create an SPF record to allow me to spoof senders?

Tags: spf

I am an IT Security professional ([my profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder)), so please understand that I have a legitimate reason for my question.

I want to have a phishing education program send realistic phishing emails, which means that I would like to spoof the senders. For instance, I would like to send from spoofed Facebook accounts. In order to make it past any potential spam or phishing filters, how can I go about doing that? Is there a way to configure SPF records to allow for that?

I have my own domain and I'm willing to jump through hoops to make this work.

My understanding of this side of email is weak, so any pointers that you might have will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were that easy to defeat SPF-based spam filters and successfully spoof Facebook, it would be a pretty useless system.

The way SPF works, in a nutshell, is that *the controller of a domain* adds a record to their DNS zone, listing the servers which *they* wish to allow as legitimate senders for that domain. On receiving an e-mail, any destination server can look up this record, and compare the IP address the mail is coming from against the rules in this record.

Without being able to control Facebook's DNS zone, you can't allow yourself to send mails from there.

The only way around it is to use some of the classic phishing techniques, like registering a domain sufficiently similar to facebook.com to trick users into thinking the mail is legitimate. Because you control the phishing domain, you can authorise yourself to send mails using SPF, DKIM, etc from *that* domain.

Incidentally, the SPF record for `facebook.com` (after following a redirect) is `"v=spf1 ip4:69.63.179.25 ip4:69.63.178.128/25 ip4:69.63.184.0/25 ip4:66.220.144.128/25 ip4:66.220.155.0/24 ip4:69.171.232.0/25 ip4:66.220.157.0/25 ip4:69.171.244.0/24 mx -all"`. The `-all` at the end means "Deny all IPs which do not match any previous rule" (sometimes known as "hardfail", as opposed to a `~all` "softfail" which can be used if you're not sure your rules are completely inclusive), as shown by [this handy checker/decoder tool](http://spf.myisp.ch/).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, if I have a registered domain with SPF records for MY domain, I can still send emails with facebook.com as the spoofed sender, but the receiving email server looks up the server/domain SPF records, and will get Facebook's listing of the allowed servers, which I won't be on. I can either register alternate domains, or hope that the receiving email server does not perform an SPF lookup. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @schroeder Yep, that's pretty much the purpose of SPF right there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add a protected spf record to your domain they are already ready for spoofed mails no need to do anything extra.

If you don't want spoofed email - https://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/spf

If you want spoofed emails - do nothing

You can easily send spoofed email using php [**mail()**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.mail.php)